# Is it possible to have an autocomplete text box in Symfony/bootstrap?

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, symfony, jquery-ui-autocomplete, symfony-2.4

I'm using Symfony 2.4 with the Braincrafted Bootstrap bundle. I have been searching for a way to have an autocompleting text box in Bootstrap but it appears I need an external library to do this ("Typeahead"?).

Firstly, is it definitely not possible to do this natively with Bootstrap?
And secondly, are there any recommended alternatives besides Typeahead?

Thanks

Answer (score 11):

A *typeahead* can be done with Symfony2 although it might take some time. Here is a **step-by-step** example:

#### The entity:

Since all *(or at least most)* forms in Symfony2 are mapped to entities you should start here. One important part of the entity you want a *typeahead* for is the `__toString` method. In this example we have an `Address` entity:

```
class Address
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message="Please enter an address")
     */
    protected $addressstring;

    public function __toString()
    {
        return $this->getAddressstring();
    }        
}
```

#### The form:

Now that we have our nice little `Address` lets add it to the `EventType` form. In the `buildForm` method we add our *address field*:

```
$builder->add(
    $builder->create(
        'address', 
        'text',
        ['attr' => ['class' => 'address_typeahead']]
    )
);
```

Notice that the field type is **text** and not *entity*. This gives us the advantage of a text-input instead of a stupid dropdown or checkbox thingy. Also we add a `class` attribute to get the field quickly in `javascript`.

#### The template:

Let's create a simple form template:

```
<form action="{{ path('event_add') }}" method="post" {{ form_enctype(form) }}>
    {{ form_widget(form) }}
    <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Create Event" />
</form>
```

And also add some `javascript` below:

```
$('.address_typeahead').typeahead({
    source: function (query, process) {
        var addressobj = $(this).parent();
        return $.get('{{ path('events_address_typeahead') }}', { 'addr': query }, function (data) {
            return process(data);
        });
    }
});
```

#### The action:

We are almost there. But the `typeaheadAction` is missing. Let's add it to our controller of choice:

```
/**
 * @Route("/address/typeahead", name="events_address_typeahead")
 * @Method("GET")
 */
public function addressTypeaheadAction(Request $request)
{
    $addresses = // get all addresses e.g. from a repository

    return new JsonResponse(
        array_map(
            function ($val) {
                return (string) $val;
            },
            $addresses
        )
    );
}
```

*Typeahead* should now already present you with some nice options in your form.

#### The transformer:

The last thing we need to do here is to add a `DataTransformer`. With this Symfony2 is able to *transform* the value of a form field into another type *(or in our case into an entity)*. So lets quickly create an `AddressTransformer`:

```
class StringToAddressTransformer implements DataTransformerInterface
{   
    /**
     * transforms the Address-Object into a String
     */
    public function transform($addrobj)
    {
        if (!$addrobj) {
            return null;
        }

        return $addrobj->__toString();
    }

    /**
     * Reverts Transformation from String to Address Object
     */
    public function reverseTransform($address)
    {

        if (null === $address) {
            return null;
        }

        // .. do anything to transform the string into an object

        return $addrobj;
    }
}
```

This transformer is really doing the magic for us! The final step is to add it to our form. Change your `buildForm` method from step 2 as follows:

```
$builder->add(
    $builder->create(
        'address', 
        'text',
        ['attr' => ['class' => 'address_typeahead']]
    )->addModelTransformer(new StringToAddressTransformer())
);
```

Aaaaaand you are done!

- [Doc about DataTransformer](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/data_transformers.html)
- [Older project of me where this example is from](https://bitbucket.org/ferdynator/siyabonga/)

Comment: +1, but becareful, if he have more than one field, he have to use a new field type, but great tut :)

Comment: Yeah good point to keep in mind. And thank you ;)

Comment: Wow thanks for the detailed response. I'll give this a try tomorrow, cheers! Will it work with 0.10.2 of http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/ ?

Comment: I don't know. I used the bootstrap v2 one. You need to check this out yourself.

Comment: Nice overall explanation. I have a 2 questions: 1) where is 'address_typeahead' defined? 2) how to do this with multiple addresses? Thx

Comment: @eddy147 the class `address_typeahead` is simply used for the Javascript selector above. Do you mean multiple address imput fields? Simply add more inputs to your form-builder in the same way. If you want to have multiple address fields (e.g. stree, city...) you have to be a little more crafty. Either split everything up and do all the steps above for all fields separately or do some funky server-side splitting of the provided string.